# fn JSTL not supported

Tags: java, jstl, appfuse

when am using `${fn:contains()}"`  it causes the following exception:

```
org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl.parser.ParseException: EL functions are not supported
```

How can i solve this exception?

and if I need to download a newer version of jstl.jar & standard.jar could any one send me a link?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are trying to use this expression as an attribute of some JSTL tag:

```
<c:if test = "${fn:contains()}">...</c:if>
```

If so, make sure that you imported JSTL taglib of version 1.1 (note the URI - it should contain `jsp`):

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: Thanks axtavt , yes am using the `<c:if test = "${fn:contains()}">...</c:if>` inside `<c:forEach` . Is there another way to do the same functionality of `fn:contains()`

Comment: @Ali: Have you checked taglib declaration?

Comment: Yes, an i changed it to `<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri ="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`, The exception has been solved but the form didn't bind correctly. Any suggestions ? Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3):

You need the function tag library declaration also.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try axtavt's answer and if it is still not working, add `<%@ page isELIgnored ="false" %>` at the top of the jsp.